# Can I have captcha in google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, captcha

I'm deploying an aplicattion in Google Apps Script, and I need the implementation of a captcha on it, how can I include captcha in Google App Script?

Comment: I tried registering an Apps Script URL to get [reCAPTCHA](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin#list), and it wouldn't allow the Apps Script URL to be registered.  [Getting started](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/start)

Answer (score 2):

Know it's an old question, but had the same issue recently.
In short, Yes, and you can add [reCaptcha](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/).

See the [readme and sample files](https://github.com/Spencer-Easton/Apps-Script-reCAPTCHA-sample) and then adapt to your needs.

Code.gs has the basics you need to only have to use javascript as oppose to php for responses.

Comment: Thanks! You made my day :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.
Here is a tutorial I posted today on my website.

[reCAPCHA with Google Apps Script](http://www.googleappsscript.org/recent-additions/recaptchawithgoogleappsscript)

The tricky thing is the domain name when you register for a Website to use reCAPTCHA. Since Apps Script webapps are hosted in an iFrame, you need to use domain of iFrame. If you do an analysis of Apps Script Webapp, you will find that all the apps have an iFrame on a temporary domain like xsdsdfjsdfks.googleusercontent.com. So you need to resgister domain  googleusercontent.com in order to get a site-key and secret-key pair.